Как вызвать итоговое число
У меня есть код, (функция randomFloat()) который с 1.00, добавляет каждые к примеру 10млс добавляет к этой одиничке по 0.01, до достижения конечного числа(функция Random()), как мне сделать так, что бы ещё до достижения конечного числа, его показывало на втором display
Вот код js,html:


const oneStepTime = 100;
const display = document.getElementById("display");
const timerDisp = document.getElementById("timer");

function randomFloat(maxNumber, maxStep, minStep) {
  let acc = 1.00;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    let step = 0.01;
    if (maxNumber - acc > step) {
      acc += step;
    } else {
      acc = maxNumber;
      clearInterval(interval);
      setTimeout(() => {
        display.innerText = "";
        run();
      }, 1000)
    }
    display.innerText = acc.toFixed(2) + "x";
  }, oneStepTime);

}

function run() {
  let count = 3;
  const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timerDisp.innerText = count;
    count--;
    if (count < 0) {
      clearInterval(countdownInterval);
      timerDisp.innerText = '';
      randomFloat(Random(), 10, 1);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function Random() {
  const min = 1;
  const max = 5;
  return Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * 100) / 100;
}

run()
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="display2"></div>
<div id="timer"></div>



Заранее спасибо!

Сохраняйте результат функции Random в переменную, а потом выводите переменную и передавайте её в функцию randomFloat:


const oneStepTime = 100;
const display = document.getElementById("display");
const display2 = document.getElementById("display2");
const timerDisp = document.getElementById("timer");

function randomFloat(maxNumber, maxStep, minStep) {
  let acc = 1.00;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    let step = 0.01;
    if (maxNumber - acc > step) {
      acc += step;
    } else {
      acc = maxNumber;
      clearInterval(interval);
      setTimeout(() => {
        display.innerText = "";
        display2.innerText = "";
        run();
      }, 1000)
    }
    display.innerText = acc.toFixed(2) + "x";
  }, oneStepTime);

}

function run() {
  let count = 3;
  const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timerDisp.innerText = count;
    count--;
    if (count < 0) {
      clearInterval(countdownInterval);
      timerDisp.innerText = '';
      const randomNumber = Random();
      display2.innerText = randomNumber;
      randomFloat(randomNumber, 10, 1);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function Random() {
  const min = 1;
  const max = 5;
  return Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * 100) / 100;
}

function button() { disp2.innerText = randomNumber; }

run()
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="display2"></div>
<div id="timer"></div>



Вывод переменной при нажатии на кнопку:


const oneStepTime = 100;
const display = document.getElementById("display");
const display2 = document.getElementById("display2");
const timerDisp = document.getElementById("timer");
let randomNumber;

function randomFloat(maxNumber, maxStep, minStep) {
  let acc = 1.00;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    let step = 0.01;
    if (maxNumber - acc > step) {
      acc += step;
    } else {
      acc = maxNumber;
      clearInterval(interval);
      setTimeout(() => {
        display.innerText = "";
        display2.innerText = "";
        run();
      }, 1000)
    }
    display.innerText = acc.toFixed(2) + "x";
  }, oneStepTime);

}

function run() {
  let count = 3;
  const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timerDisp.innerText = count;
    count--;
    if (count < 0) {
      clearInterval(countdownInterval);
      timerDisp.innerText = '';
      randomNumber = Random();
      randomFloat(randomNumber, 10, 1);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function Random() {
  const min = 1;
  const max = 5;
  return Math.round((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) * 100) / 100;
}

function button() { display2.innerText = randomNumber; }

run()
#Button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="display2"></div>
<div id="timer"></div>
<button id="Button" onclick="button()"></button>




И возможно вызвать итоговое число на дисплей 2 понажатии на кнопку? я просто сделал так:

function button() {
disp2.innerText = randomNumber;
}
Но у меня не вышло

Переменная находится вне области видимости функции button(). Необходимо объявить переменную вне функции. Добавил пример

Большое спасибо!
